# How to connect NodeMCU to NRF24L01

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, nrf24l01+

I need to connect NodeMCU and NRF24L01. where I'm receiving data from another NRF24L01 Transmission. I managed to connect to a WiFi network but the data receiving is not taking place as expected. Here is my code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "RF24.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

RF24 myRadio(7, 8);
const char* ssid = "******";
const char* password = "********";
struct package
{
    int id = 0;
    float longitude = 0.0;
    float latitude = 0.0;
    char text[100] = "empty";
};

byte addresses[][6] = {"0"};

typedef struct package Package;
Package data;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(1000);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connecting");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
     delay(500);
     Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("success!");
    Serial.print("IP Address is: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    myRadio.begin();
    myRadio.setChannel(115);
    myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
    myRadio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
    myRadio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[0]);
    myRadio.startListening();
}

void loop()
{

    if (myRadio.available())
    {
        while (myRadio.available())
        {
            myRadio.read(&data, sizeof(data));
        }
        Serial.print("\nPackage:");
        Serial.print(data.id);
        Serial.print("\n");
        Serial.println(data.longitude);
        Serial.println(data.latitude);
        Serial.println(data.text);
    }
}
```

Any idea on why this is not receiving data as expected?. This somehow managed to connect to my WIFI successfully. Here are my pin connection 
[image]

Comment: 7, 8 should be pin numbers? io 5 to io 11 are internal flash memory QIO SPI pins. if you connected the module to D7, D8, use D7, D8 constants

Comment: Hi @Juraj I used D7 and D8. i have updated my question with an image of the pin connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dx pin labels on NodeMcu and Wemos/Lolin boards do not correspond to esp8266 internal io pin numbers. The pins_arduino.h file in core defines Dx constants which map internal io numbers to Dx labels.

Use `RF24 myRadio(D7, D8);`